# Why does the weather app need a Microsoft account?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, apps, microsoft-account

I purchased a Nokia 635 running Windows Phone 8.1. I'm trying to set up the Weather App, which came preinstalled on the phone. When I attempt to run the app, I'm given two choices: *Update* and *Share* (no other setup, like ZIP code or location services).

When I tap *Share*, it wants to do something with *OneNote* or *Messaging* (I'm not sure what, as this seems very uninteresting). When I tap *Update*, I'm told: ***Microsoft account required***. When I click *Cancel*, the app closes with an error.

Why does the weather app need more than a ZIP code or location? Why does it need an account?

Comment: It sounds like you're in the store, rather than within the weather app itself?

Answer (score 2):

So I guess this is the first app your downloading from the store? For each download or update you need a Microsoft Account to which your license is bound.

I really recommend setting an account up because there are a lot more things your phone can do when synched with a MS account.

Comment: The weather app was preloaded on the phone. I don't use app stores and clouds (if I can avoid them).

Comment: of course you are right to do so. However, that's the reason you can't update the app.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Account required error comes when you are trying to Update the app to latest version. Apparently there is no way for you to avoid it if you don't intend to associate a Microsoft Account with WP.

As for Share, it just provides you a way to share the weather stats via some apps which support sharing like Messaging, OneNote, etc.